# PHP for send a email for more than one recipients automatically at a given time

Tags: php

i want to send a email for more than one recipients automatically every day 8:00 AM output of following sql Query

```
$sql10 ="SELECT     `X`.`wdate`,`X`.`line`,`X`.`style_no`,`X`.`po_no`,`P`.`order_qty`,`X`.`Line_O    ut`,`X`.`Final_QC_Out`,`X`.`Iron_Out`,`X`.`Refinal_Out`,`X`.`Packing_In`,`X`.     `Warehouse_In`   FROM(SELECT     `Q`.`wdate`,`Q`.`line`,`Q`.`style_no`,`Q`.`po_no`,SUM(IF(`Q`.`place`='Line_Ou    t',`Q`.`bsum`,0)) AS Line_Out,      SUM(IF(`Q`.`place`='Final_QC_Out',`Q`.`bsum`,0)) AS     Final_QC_Out,SUM(IF(`Q`.`place`='Iron_Out',`Q`.`bsum`,0)) AS Iron_Out, SUM(IF(`Q`.`place`='Refinal_Out',`Q`.`bsum`,0)) AS Refinal_Out, SUM(IF(`Q`.`place`='Packing_In',`Q`.`bsum`,0)) AS Packing_In, SUM(IF(Q.place='Warehouse_In',Q.bsum,0)) AS Warehouse_In FROM(SELECT `T`.`fac_code` , T.style_no , T.po_no , SUM( T.bcount ) AS bsum , `T`.`wdate` , `T`.`Place`,`T`.`line` FROM ( SELECT `W`.`fac_code` , `W`.`barcode_id` , `B`.`style_no` , `B`.`po_no` , `B`.`size` , `B`.`colour` , COUNT( `W`.`barcode_id` ) as `bcount`,`W`.`wdate`,`W`.`place`,`W`.`line` FROM wherin_tbl AS W , barcode_tbl AS B WHERE `W`.`barcode_id` = `B`.`barcode_id` GROUP BY `W`.`barcode_id` ,`W`.`fac_code`,`W`.`place`,`W`.`line`,`W`.`wdate` ) AS T WHERE `T`.`fac_code`='$_POST[fac_code]' AND `T`.`wdate` BETWEEN '$_POST[frdate]' AND '$_POST[trdate]'  GROUP BY `T`.`line`,`T`.`place`,`T`.`po_no`,`T`.`wdate`) AS Q GROUP BY `Q`.`wdate`,`Q`.`po_no`,`Q`.`line` ) as X, po_tbl AS P WHERE `X`.`po_no`=`P`.`po_no` AND `P`.`fac_code`='$_POST[fac_code]' ORDER BY `X`.`wdate`,`X`.`line`";
```

---

My Script:

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0'> ";
echo "<tr> <th>Date</th><th>Line</th> <th>Style No</th> <th>PO No</th><th    bgcolor='#CCCCFF'>Order Qty</th><th>Line Out</th><th>Final QC Out</th><th>Iron Out</th><th>Refinal Out</th><th>Packing In</th><th>Warehouse In</th>";
while ($row10=mysql_fetch_array($result10)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['wdate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td> Line" . $row10['line'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['style_no'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['po_no'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#CCCCFF'>" . $row10['order_qty'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['Line_Out'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['Final_QC_Out'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['Iron_Out']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['Refinal_Out'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['Packing_In'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row10['Warehouse_In'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

---

database structure for email address:

```
 email_tbl
sn | email         |location |
1  |test@vtex.com  | HO      |
2  |test2@vtex.com |TGK      |
3  |test3@vtex.com |HO       |
```

Comment: "pls send me PHP codes for do it " nope.

Comment: Please stop posting noise like "regards bla bla" etc. This does not help atall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should solve your immediate problem.

The first block, which builds $msg, is based upon the code you provided since I don't have enough insight into your database setup to write something more modern. mysql_fetch_array and the whole group of mysql_ functions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, etc.) and should no longer be used. But since you've opened the database this way, I use it in the second code block too. Please consider getting comfortable with the PDO class, which is a vast improvement and will make your PHP/SQL a lot more stable (http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).

```
$msg = "<table border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0'> ";
$msg .= "<tr> <th>Date</th><th>Line</th> <th>Style No</th> <th>PO No</th><th    bgcolor='#CCCCFF'>Order Qty</th><th>Line Out</th><th>Final QC Out</th><th>Iron Out</th><th>Refinal Out</th><th>Packing In</th><th>Warehouse In</th>";
while ( $row10 = mysql_fetch_array( $result10 ) ) {
  $msg .= "<tr>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['wdate'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td> Line" . $row10['line'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['style_no'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['po_no'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td bgcolor='#CCCCFF'>" . $row10['order_qty'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['Line_Out'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['Final_QC_Out'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['Iron_Out']. "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['Refinal_Out'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['Packing_In'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "<td>" . $row10['Warehouse_In'] . "</td>";
  $msg .= "</tr>";
}
$msg .= "</table>";

$query = "SELECT email FROM email_tbl";
if ( !$result = mysql_query( $query ) ) {
  $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
  die($message);
}
$to = '';
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  $to .= $row['email'] . ',';
}
rtrim( $to, "," );
mysql_free_result( $result );

$subject = "Morning email from Gayan";

$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com';

if ( mail( $to, $subject, $msg, $headers ) ) {
  echo "Email sent successfully<br>";
} else {
  echo "ERROR sending email<br>";
}
```

Comment: Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\AppServ\www\VOGUE\productionreport47.php on line 93
ERROR sending email                                                                                                                 ........Above Error Occurred..................

Comment: The warning is telling you the problem

Comment: @GayanChaturanga I added a $headers variable, which should solve the immediate problem. You appear to be running on an improperly configured system, since $headers shouldn't be necessary. You may want to update your php.ini file.

Comment: Hi...Ben Shoval / SparK

Comment: @BenShoval thanx for the support..but problem still not solve because now it asking to modify "PHP.ini " file. still studying the way to setup exchange server setting to ini file. i thing script is working now.

Comment: @GayanChaturanga I'm glad to hear that the problem posed in your question has been solved. Please mark the answer from SparK and me as the answer so others can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: @GayanChaturanga Since you asked for advice in your question, not just an answer, let me offer some on your Exchange issue... While you'll likely get things working in the immediate sense with Exchange through tinkering, using an Exchange-based setup with PHP's mail function is going to be a source of headaches over time. You might want to consider using a third-party email service like mailjet (which offers 6,000 free emails a month) or sendGrid (I have no affiliation with either one other than as a user).

Comment: @Ben Shoval      I modified my PHP.INI file to send mail via my Exchange server. now its give this error.         "Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated in C:\AppServ\www\innov\email.php on line 14"